# Starting Cascading Activities on Button Click

Tags: java, android

I have various activites in my android application lets say Activity1,Activity2,Activity3 etc

All are started by intent object on button Click or list view selection event.On Some activites like in Activity1 i store a bundle inside an intent object and then start an Activity2, On the Second Activity the startActivity() method doesnot work is it memory related issue like intent too heavy to go to next Activity3.

Following is my code

```
Class Activity2 extends Activity
{
     private Intent i;
     private Button btn;
     @Override 
      protected void onCreate(Bundle b)
      {
            //super...
            i=new Intent(Activity2.this,Activity3.class);
            //btn=.....
```

//following is button click event from which i will navigate to Activity3

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {    

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(i); //here it crashed
    }});
```

}

Is it memory related issue or coding problem? if coding problem then how else Activity can be started other than intent.

Following is Log

```
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.viva_project/com.example.viva_project.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:942)
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500):     at com.example.viva_project.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:309)
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500):     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:3851)
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1191)
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
02-05 02:55:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4500):     ... 12 more



protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    connectThread.killConnectThread();
     }
```

Comment: what error do you get in the LogCat?

Comment: Can you share code from MainActivity.java's onPause()  at com.example.viva_project.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:309) there is NullPointerException

Comment: Sorry i did override that sir it is shared now

Comment: what is @ MainActivity.java line 309?

Comment: connectThread.killConnectThread();

Comment: It should not have been the problem since connectThread gets called from other button event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to mention all 3 Activities in your Menifest.

Comment: I have mentioned all of them and tested them one by one from my Splash Activity using intent and action attribute from manifest

Comment: Can you try by Removing your onPause() method?

Comment: Your problem is not with what you asked.. Its because connectThread.killConnectThread();

Comment: Thanks Sagar for your time

Comment: Anytime buddy, If you really mean that then Accept my answer  instead of thanking me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.viva_project.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:309)
```

the problem is here:

```
connectThread.killConnectThread();
```

`connectThread` is `null` and you are tryin to execute the method `killConnectThread()`!

Be sure to have Activity1, Activity2, and Activity3 registered into your `Manifest.xml`